# how to send the option value to an action class

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp-tags

```
<select id="state" name="state" class="form_select1">
  <option value="">--Select State--</option>

  <c:forEach items="${SpeakOut_statesList}" var="country">
    <option value="${country.stateId}">${country.stateName}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I want to save the particular `stateId` in database when particular state is selected. What do I have to do in order to send the option value to action class using Struts framework and Herbinate?

Comment: Which version of Struts? If the select is named appropriately, and you know either version of Struts (or can find the docs) you know the first part (JSP -> Action). Is your question regarding Hibernate?

Comment: using Struts2 version. when I select country.stateName , it is getting saved in database using hybernate... but I want to save country.stateId instead... please advice..Thanks

Comment: So save the id instead? Which Struts 2 version?